# How to scrape the javascript element by using requests and buetifulsoup

Tags: javascript, python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

How to scrape the element (series: ~~~~ until ~~~~ data: [[90, 63000],[91, 68000]]}] and convert it to dict or list type?

This is the javascript in the website:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        
            var chart;
            var screenWidth = window.innerWidth * 0.935 * 1;    
            $(document).ready(function() {
                                    
                    series: [{
                    
                    name: 'Water',
                    data: [[90, 50000],[91, 53000]]
                  },{
                    
                    name: 'Tea',
                    data: [[90, 47000],[91, 53000]]
                  },{
                    
                    name: 'Tonic',
                    data: [[90, 63000],[91, 68000]]
                  }]
                });
                
                
            });
                
        </script>
```

This is my error python code:

```
    s=requests.get(url,params = data,headers)
    data= BeautifulSoup(s.text,'lxml')
    jsons= data.find_all('script')[1].text
    datas= jsons.find('series:')
    last= jsons.find(']]')
    new=''
    for x in range(datas+6,last+2):
        new+=jsons[x]

    newdata = eval(new)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the data is not a json, it's an javascript object. Even if you select the json and apply `json.loads` it will fail. Hence, you will need 3rd party libraries that can convert javascript object to json.

I use `demjson` - https://github.com/dmeranda/demjson

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import demjson

html = """<script type="text/javascript">
        
            var chart;
            var screenWidth = window.innerWidth * 0.935 * 1;    
            $(document).ready(function() {
                                    
                    series: [{
                    
                    name: 'Water',
                    data: [[90, 50000],[91, 53000]]
                  },{
                    
                    name: 'Tea',
                    data: [[90, 47000],[91, 53000]]
                  },{
                    
                    name: 'Tonic',
                    data: [[90, 63000],[91, 68000]]
                  }]
                });
                
                
            });
                
        </script>"""

script = soup.find("script").text.strip()
data = demjson.decode(script[script.index("{"):script.index("});")] + "}")

print(type(data))
print("-" * 10)
print(data)
```

Output:

```
<class 'dict'>
----------
{'series': [{'name': 'Water', 'data': [[90, 50000], [91, 53000]]}, {'name': 'Tea', 'data': [[90, 47000], [91, 53000]]}, {'name': 'Tonic', 'data': [[90, 63000], [91, 68000]]}]}
```